# Google.Apis.Auth Source Code c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

Recently I've been using a few of Google's apis and I've come across various GitHub repositories that contain copies of classes from Google's APIs. (eg [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker](https://github.com/Schwenkner/SugarSyncNet/blob/97007da63d5b73ac4f4e164f2410dc25887110e1/google-api-dotnet-client-e6585033994b/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.WinRT/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs))  Curiosity has got the better of me and I want to take a look of some of these and in particular the Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 library.  I've tried using the [discovery service](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list#try-it) mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) without success (i've got found an oauth library but doesn't seem to be the one i'm looking for).

Any help in getting the source for this would be much appreciated.

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a bit more digging (and a bit of luck) I've managed to stumble on what I was looking for and make myself look daft.

I anyone finds themselves here with the same issue, I drilled through a bit more of the source on the google-api github page and found what I wanted in the [Support directory](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Support).

Sorted. Friday pint time.